# push notifications for wordpress site?

Tags: android, wordpress

How can i setup a push notification for my wordpress site. I have a wordpress site and its app. So i need to notify via app whenever any post is added to my site. When i search on internet i found that there are alots of plugins available. But is there any method without adding any plugins? If there is no such ways which will be the best plugin that i can use? I saw many like, [PushOverNotifications](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pushover-notifications/)
[push notifiation for posts](http://codecanyon.net/item/push-notifications-for-posts/6868260?ref=panah100)
etc..
Can i write my own plugin? if yes is threre any preferable methods..??
please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `PHP` web service which would be checking post updates on the site and send push notifications. This [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) should be useful for push notification implementation.

Comment: Thank u for the answer..
But this is only the push notification for the mobile, i would like to know at the site side.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Pusher Beams with your WordPress Website for Push notification. You can write your plugin for this purpose. And you can also check this plugin for help.

[Pusher for wordpress](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/pusher-for-wordpress)
Here is the link below for the official link Pusher Beams:

[Pusher Beams Push Notification](https://pusher.com/beams)